# Problem accessing webservices using javascript in firefox

Tags: javascript, web-services

I am trying to access my webservices that is build in .Net using Javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Web service</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function httptest(){

            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var params = "";
            var RetFlag = "Webmail-"+ false;            
            http.open("Post", "http://localhost:3624/_anet/wsCoverageValidate.asmx/CheckCoverage" , false);         
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
            http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");       
            http.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200)
                {   
                    var resp=http.responseText; 
                    alert(resp);
                }
            }           
            http.send(params);      
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="float: left; width: 100%; background-color: Gray;">
        <button id="btngo1" value="Go" type="submit" onclick="httptest()">
            Go
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my html page with javascript. Now it runs fine with Internet Explorer, but it creates problem while accessing from firefox. It gives me javascript error as

```
Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
```

, in Error console. I searched a lot for this, but yet no success.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: no. while debugging javascript it send to function, while webservices been accessed.

Comment: try jQuery - it is cross browser compliant

Comment: Can you give me any helpful link, that can show to to access webservices using jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have got the answer for my issue, it cannot be tested on local. Mozilla provide such type of security.

When i uploaded my html file on my server and called from my PC then it works fine. ]

I got the answer from [here](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=28472)

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Download jQuery and add the source in your HTML page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Follow this tutorial for more information - http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

To access a webservice

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function httptest(){

    $.post('http://localhost:3624/_anet/wsCoverageValidate.asmx/CheckCoverage', function(data) {
      alert(data);
    });
    </script>
```